# Appending and removing specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove specific a href tags that were appended to the html:

jQuery:

First function generates the link:

```
var edit_link = function (id, price) {
    var args = ('<a target="_blank" class="tag-res" href="/reservations/database/edit/'+id+'">Res: '+id+ '('+price+')</a>');
    return args;
}
```

Second appending the link upon selection of values.

```
var ajaxHandler = function(decrement) {
    return function(value){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/police/get_res_price?price=' + value,
            success: function (data) {
                var initial_price = parseInt($('.give-me-money').val());
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(obj, function (booking_price, value) {
                    if (decrement) {
                        initial_price -= parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
                        $(edit_link(value.DBASE_ID, value.BOOKING_PRICE)).remove();
                    } else {
                        //case booking is null alert
                        if (value.BOOKING_PRICE === 0 || value.BOOKING_PRICE <= 0) {
                            alert('There is a problem with Reservation: ' + value.DBASE_ID + '\n\nProblem: Price is 0');
                        }
                        initial_price += parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
                        $('div[name=res_list]').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.res_selected_list').append(edit_link(value.DBASE_ID, value.BOOKING_PRICE));
                    }
                });
                $('.give-me-money').val(initial_price); //set total
            }
        });
        this.qs1.cache();
        this.qs2.cache();
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div name="res_list" class="row-space-2 form-group hidden">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputTooltip">Selected reservations:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 res_selected_list"></div>
</div>
```

Append working fine but trying to remove each appended element with: `$(edit_link(value.DBASE_ID, value.BOOKING_PRICE)).remove();`
nothing happenes. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
$(edit_link(value.DBASE_ID, value.BOOKING_PRICE)).remove();
```

it actually creates a new item and removes it.

You need to be able to find the created item and remove it from your DOM.
For this you can introduce a `data-id` attribute:

```
var edit_link = function (id, price) {
    var args = '<a target="_blank" data-id="' + id + '" class="tag-res" href="/reservations/database/edit/'+id+'">Res: '+id+ '('+price+')</a>';
    return args;
}
```

Then, remove it using:

```
$('.tag-res[data-id="' + value.DBASE_ID + '"]').remove();
```

Comment: Just like i thought adding data attribute to html, thanks!